# how to fix "Task 'test' is not in your gulpfile" error when using gulpfile

Tags: node.js, gulp, hyperledger-fabric

```js
/*
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
const requireDir = require('require-dir');
const gulp = require('gulp');

// Require all tasks in gulp/tasks, including subfolders
requireDir('./build/tasks', {recurse: true});

gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'check_license'], () => {
 // This will only run if the lint task is successful...
});
```

[screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmHq3.png)
I'm new in the hyperledger community, I tried to test fabric-sdk-node project that I cloned from github. When I try 'gulp test' it hsows me an error "Task 'test' is not in your gulpfile".
how can I solve it ?
this is my gulpfile.js

Comment: You have to show your gulpfile.js.  It apparently does npt have a task named `test` in it.

Comment: that's true it doesn't contain a test task, but the folder /build/tasks contain a test.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with that `require-dir` package for awhile.  The only way I could get it to work was:

```
// in './build/tasks/test.js'

const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

// note the use of gulp.task syntax, **not** function test()

gulp.task('test', function() {
  console.log("in test task");
  return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

---

```
// in 'gulpfile.js'

const requireDir = require('require-dir');
const gulp = require('gulp');

// Require all tasks in gulp/tasks, including subfolders
requireDir('./build/tasks', { recurse: true });

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('test'));  // note I have gulp v4 on my machine
```

This does run the `test` task successfully, transpiling the `scss` file in this case.

Despite the fact that I am running gulp4 I had to use the `gulp.task('test')` syntax to get it to work.  It would not work if the `test` task was defined like so:

```
function test() {
  console.log("in test function");

  return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
};
```

which I would normally use.  (With `gulp.task('default', gulp.series(test));`)

Are your tasks created as `gulp.task('sdfsdfsdfs')`?  I assume they are since you are using the `gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'check_license']` type of syntax.

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept the answer then - click the check mark just below the up/down arrows next to the answer.